# its possible install telegram-cli in windows

Tags: windows, api, command-line-interface, telegram

Is it Possible to install [telegramcli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg)  in Windows? 
I want to compile .exe file.

this source run in ubuntu but not worked php shell 
First of all, the binary is now in ./bin folder and is named telegram-cli. So be careful, not to use old binary.

Second, config folder is now ${HOME}/.telegram-cli

Third, database is not compatible with older versions, so you'll have to login again.

Fourth, in peer_name '#' are substitued to '@'. (Not applied to appending of '#%d' in case of two peers having same name).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) to compile the original source code into `telegram-cli` windows binary.

Follow this guide (official): https://github.com/vysheng/tg/blob/master/README-Cygwin.md